# Python convert user input properly formatted as an array into an int array

Tags: python, arrays

I was wondering if there was a way to take a properly formatted user input array, IE '[2,1,1]' as user input, and then convert that into a int array of [2,2,1].

Comment: Python has lists, not arrays.

Comment: Then why do I import "array"?

Comment: I have no idea. Your question does not show any indication of you doing so.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to safely parse a string representing a literal Python expression into a Python object:

```
import ast

ast.literal_eval('[2,1,1]')
# [2, 1, 1]
```

If the string is valid JSON, then you could instead use `json. loads`:

```
import json

json.loads('[2,1,1]')
# [2, 1, 1]
```

Of the two, when the string is both a literal Python expression and JSON, `json.loads` is faster.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the info! ast.literal_eval(input()) works but replacing input with say s = input() ast.literal_eval(s) doesn't seem to work. What's up with that?

Comment: @Jelly Those should be equivalent. Something else is probably wrong.

Comment: @Jelly: What is the full traceback error message? ("Does not work" is almost never enough information for us to give help.)

Comment: I don't know anymore, I took out my 's' string and just used input() to get my data, then I put 's' back in to get the error for you, but now it seems to work. I must've been making a typo somwhere.